# How can I tell a comment is from the question asker?

Tags: support, comments

Lets say a user John has posted a question, and he enters comments on various answers he received. Is it indicated somehow that John is the questioner, like for example, "John (asker)"?

Sometimes when I have to analyze whether the answers have solved the questioner's problem, I have to scroll up to find who asked and understand his comments.

Comment: -1?? for not realizing some thing that's not so obvious... Thank You..

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/faq#vote-differences

Comment: o. Thanks agf.. that explains..

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This is already done, it's just not particularly noticeable. Check out the greyish box behind my name in these comments in a question I posted. The same style is applied to answers posted by a questioner.

#### Stack Overflow

[image]

#### Meta Stack Overflow

[image]

Comment: O. ye there I see it. Now it should solve my problem. shouldn't we make it obvious that anyone who sees it will know?

Comment: There I saw it in my own comment..

Comment: There it was again!

Comment: @Michael It's pretty noticeable on most sites.  If your contrast is high on a good monitor and it's still a problem, post a `[design] [bug]`.

Comment: @MatthewRead I realized I misunderstood what Jeremy was referencing and I convinced myself there was some nearly invisible difference that wasn't there.  Now that I realize what he was talking about, I realize my monitors have no problem displaying it, but merely my brain has a tough time actually noticing it.

Comment: After 2 weeks of using SO and having quite fine sight... i only saw this after i read this topic. Why not add an icon or some visible text ??

Comment: The freehand circles just earned you my upvote, and, as a result, another "Good Answer" badge.  The lesson here is that, when in doubt, use freehand circles.

Comment: Will be really helpful now that I know to look for this.  It would be good if this behavior, and probably others, were collected in a standard orientation for the SEs.

Answer (score 7):

[image]

Comment: The freehand circles make all the difference.  Without them in Jeremy's answer I still didn't notice the gray box at first.